# Какой алгоритм для рекомендательной системы выбрать SlapOne или SVD?

Tags: машинное-обучение, искусственный-интеллект

Здравствуйте, у меня есть система оценок статей, можно поставить лайк дизлайк и в качесте неявных оценок, прочитать и перелистнуть на другую статью. Прочитал много теории и встал перед выбором основного алгоритма SVD на эту тему очень много информации и информации о точности или SlapeOne, существует OpenSlapeOne, пишут что прост в реализации и показывает высокий результат